# How to update a div based on it's position relative to another div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, date

I am trying to find the best way to update the div with id "date" with the dates of the divs that are scrolled past. I thought this may be done through getting the data-date attributes however I was even having trouble obtaining the ids of the divs which are scrolled past. So in this case the content of the date div, should start out as 25 July and then as the div with id=2 passes the date div, the content of the date div should change to 25 July and so on.

index.html:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>

#comments {
float:left;
width:450px;
}

#date {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
margin-top: 20px;
border: 1px solid #A9F5F2;
background-color: #A9F5F2;
color: #6E6E6E;
font-weight: bold;
}

</style>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.js">    
</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

$(function () {
$(window).scroll(function (event) {

  var  p =  $('#date').closest('[id]');
  console.log(p); 

});
});
});
</script>
</head>
<body>


<div id="1" data-date="25 July">
comment 1 comment 1 comment 1 comment 1 comment 1 comment 1 <p>
comment 1 comment 1 comment 1 <p>
comment 1 comment 1 comment 1 <p>
</div>

<div id="2" data-date="24 July">
comment 2 comment 2 comment 2 comment 2 comment 2 comment 2 <p>
comment 2 comment 2 comment 2 <p>
comment 2 comment 2 comment 2 <p>
</div>

<div id="3" data-date="23 July">
comment 3 comment 3 comment 3 
comment 3 comment 3 comment 3 <p>
comment 3 comment 3 comment 3 <p>
comment 3 comment 3 comment 3 <p>
</div>

<div id="4" data-date="22 July">comment 4 comment 4 comment 4
comment 4 comment 4 comment 4 <p>
comment 4 comment 4 comment 4 <p>
comment 4 comment 4 comment 4
</div>

<div id="5" data-date="21 July">
comment 5 comment 5 comment 5 <p>
comment 5 comment 5 comment 5 <p>
comment 5 comment 5 comment 5 <p>
comment 5 comment 5 comment 5 <p>
comment 5 comment 5 comment 5 <p>
comment 5 comment 5 comment 5 <p>
comment 5 comment 5 comment 5 <p>
comment 5 comment 5 comment 5 <p>
comment 5 comment 5 comment 5 <p>
comment 5 comment 5 comment 5 <p>
comment 5 comment 5 comment 5 <p>
comment 5 comment 5 comment 5 <p>
comment 5 comment 5 comment 5 <p>
comment 5 comment 5 comment 5 <p>
comment 5 comment 5 comment 5 <p>
comment 5 comment 5 comment 5 <p>
</div>

<div id="date" style="float:right; position: fixed">
    25 July
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: How are you handling scrolling? Is it default browser scrolling, or some library?

Comment: Just an fyi, .closest will return the closest element based on the dom, not on position of the screen.  Remember the DOM is what any javascript and html are going to interact with, despite what is on the screen.

Comment: Alternatively to data-date and id, you could write your dates like this id='7-5-2015'.  Not quite sure what you are doing but I would ditch the data attribute and id them all with the date.

Comment: Worth pointing out: #ID selectors can not start with a number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've added a class to your date divs, such as

`<div class="myDates" id="1" data-date="25 July">`

then

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

        function viewPortCheck(el) {
            function isElementInViewport(el) {
                var rect = el.getBoundingClientRect();
                return (
                    rect.top >= 0 &&
                    rect.left >= 0 &&
                    rect.bottom <= (window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight) &&
                    rect.right <= (window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth)
                );
            }

            function givenElementInViewport(el) {
                return function() {
                    if (isElementInViewport(el)) {
                        let d = el.dataset.date;
                        $('#date').html(d);
                    }
                };
            }

            if (window.addEventListener) {
                addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', givenElementInViewport(el), false);
                addEventListener('load', givenElementInViewport(el), false);
                addEventListener('scroll', givenElementInViewport(el), false);
                addEventListener('resize', givenElementInViewport(el), false);
            } else if (window.attachEvent) {
                attachEvent('DOMContentLoaded', givenElementInViewport(el));
                attachEvent('load', givenElementInViewport(el));
                attachEvent('scroll', givenElementInViewport(el));
                attachEvent('resize', givenElementInViewport(el));
            }
        }

        $(function () {
            $(window).scroll(function (event) {
                let elems = $('.myDates');
                for(let i = 0; i < elems.length; i++ ){
                    viewPortCheck(elems[i]);
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

```css
    #comments {
        float:left;
        width:450px;
    }

    #date {
        position: absolute;
        top: 10px;
        right:10px;
        border: 1px solid #A9F5F2;
        background-color: #A9F5F2;
        color: #6E6E6E;
        font-weight: bold;
        min-width:50px;
    }

    .myDates {
        min-height: 30%;
        margin: 10% 10px;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="date" style="float:right; position: fixed">
    &nbsp;
</div>

<div class="myDates" id="1" data-date="25 July">
comment 1 comment 1 comment 1 comment 1 comment 1 comment 1 <p>
comment 1 comment 1 comment 1 <p>
comment 1 comment 1 comment 1 <p>
</div>

<div class="myDates" id="2" data-date="24 July">
comment 2 comment 2 comment 2 comment 2 comment 2 comment 2 <p>
comment 2 comment 2 comment 2 <p>
comment 2 comment 2 comment 2 <p>
</div>

<div class="myDates" id="3" data-date="23 July">
comment 3 comment 3 comment 3
comment 3 comment 3 comment 3 <p>
comment 3 comment 3 comment 3 <p>
comment 3 comment 3 comment 3 <p>
</div>

<div class="myDates" id="4" data-date="22 July">comment 4 comment 4 comment 4
comment 4 comment 4 comment 4 <p>
comment 4 comment 4 comment 4 <p>
comment 4 comment 4 comment 4
</div>

<div class="myDates" id="5" data-date="21 July">
comment 5 comment 5 comment 5 <p>
comment 5 comment 5 comment 5 <p>
comment 5 comment 5 comment 5 <p>
comment 5 comment 5 comment 5 <p>
comment 5 comment 5 comment 5 <p>
comment 5 comment 5 comment 5 <p>
comment 5 comment 5 comment 5 <p>
comment 5 comment 5 comment 5 <p>
comment 5 comment 5 comment 5 <p>
comment 5 comment 5 comment 5 <p>
comment 5 comment 5 comment 5 <p>
comment 5 comment 5 comment 5 <p>
comment 5 comment 5 comment 5 <p>
comment 5 comment 5 comment 5 <p>
comment 5 comment 5 comment 5 <p>
comment 5 comment 5 comment 5 <p>
</div>
```

Comment: Perfect! Just want I need, I'm testing it locally and for some reason it's not working as it is in the Snippet

Comment: do you get any errors in your console? can you share them?

Comment: No sorry I take that back I introduced a typo. Your code works perfectly! One more ask though are you able to comment your code cos I'm pretty new to Javascript so would be handy.

Comment: OK, I will need to do it offline and repost bc I keep accidentally posting semi written sentences here...

Comment: Thank you. Also one last thing it's a great solution but just a little jerky when scrolling. Is there anything that can be done about that?

Comment: I see..., been a bit too fast with it - left your event listener in place and added additional ones, making it going bonkers a bit...

Been playing with it a little and realise that it's a tricky situation, depending on the size of the bounding box we may have multiple target elements in viewport in which case we need to decide which one should take priority...

Comment: Hi what can you suggest?

Comment: defining a shallower region from where to substract the data-date filed, within ```isElementInViewport()``` you can set someting like:
```rect.bottom <= window.innerHeight / 2``` (halving screen height)
and similarly
```rect.top >= 100``` (to  exclude the top 100px of the screen)

note: these are arbitary values, you should consider your target device / platform etc etc - it's a fiddly thing

Answer (score 2):

You're missing a lot of code, but I threw this together - it will detect when one div hits the top of the window. Hopefully this helps you and you're able to add on the rest of the functionality you need.

https://jsfiddle.net/tobyl/uquj897s/

```
$(window).scroll(function() {

  var elemPos = $("#3").offset().top - $(window).scrollTop();
  var winPos = $(window).scrollTop();

  if (elemPos < winPos) {
    console.log("element is above window top!");
  } else {
    console.log("element has not yet hit the window top.");
  }
});
```

Comment: Great is there a way to get an attribute like data-date as the div hits the top of the window?

Answer (score 0):

Ok i dont have a full solution but here is what I got for you.

We can use [scrollLeft()](https://api.jquery.com/scrollleft/) and [scrollTop()](https://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/) to determine the position of the scroll bar (this determining the position of the page and which date we are closest to).

```
    $(window).scroll(function (event) {
var left = $(window).scrollLeft();
var top  = $(window).scrollTop();
var IDofElementIamCloseTo = someSuperCoolCalculationFunction(left,top);
  
  console.log(IDofElementIamCloseTo ); 

});

function someSuperCoolCalculationFunction(left, top){

//somehow determine how far you have moved and what is closer, maybe you can create a list of key //value pairs or make your divs a fixed width/length.  

}
```

That should get you moving.

EDIT: the other guys answer is better

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't finish because of time but based on Toby's answer this code gets the first occurrence of the class "divDate" and based on its size and location changes to the next and changes the div with id="date"... still have to do when scrolls up. Sorry any bad english xD

https://jsfiddle.net/smm7mrqn/

```
<div class="divDate" id="1" data-date="25 July">
    comment 1 comment 1 comment 1 comment 1 comment 1 comment 1 <p>
    comment 1 comment 1 comment 1 <p>
    comment 1 comment 1 comment 1 <p>
</div>

<div class="divDate" id="2" data-date="24 July">
comment 2 comment 2 comment 2 comment 2 comment 2 comment 2 <p>
comment 2 comment 2 comment 2 <p>
comment 2 comment 2 comment 2 <p>
</div>

<div class="divDate" id="3" data-date="23 July">
comment 3 comment 3 comment 3 
comment 3 comment 3 comment 3 <p>
comment 3 comment 3 comment 3 <p>
comment 3 comment 3 comment 3 <p>
</div>

<div class="divDate" id="4" data-date="22 July">comment 4 comment 4 comment 4
comment 4 comment 4 comment 4 <p>
comment 4 comment 4 comment 4 <p>
comment 4 comment 4 comment 4
</div>

<div class="divDate" id="5" data-date="21 July">
comment 5 comment 5 comment 5 <p>
comment 5 comment 5 comment 5 <p>
comment 5 comment 5 comment 5 <p>
comment 5 comment 5 comment 5 <p>
comment 5 comment 5 comment 5 <p>
comment 5 comment 5 comment 5 <p>
comment 5 comment 5 comment 5 <p>
comment 5 comment 5 comment 5 <p>
comment 5 comment 5 comment 5 <p>
comment 5 comment 5 comment 5 <p>
comment 5 comment 5 comment 5 <p>
comment 5 comment 5 comment 5 <p>
comment 5 comment 5 comment 5 <p>
comment 5 comment 5 comment 5 <p>
comment 5 comment 5 comment 5 <p>
comment 5 comment 5 comment 5 <p>
</div>

<div id="date" style="float:right; position: fixed">
    25 July
</div>

<script>
var $currDiv = $(".divDate").first();
$(window).scroll(function() {
  var elemPos = $currDiv.offset().top - $(window).scrollTop();
  var elemHeight = $currDiv.css("height");
  var winPos = $(window).scrollTop();

  if (elemPos <= 0) {
    $('#date').html($currDiv.attr("data-date"));
  }
  if((parseInt(elemPos) + parseInt(elemHeight)) <= 0){
    $currDiv = $currDiv.next(".divDate");
  } 
});
</script>
```

Comment: HI yes this is good too! Can you please add the code to deal with scrolling back up?